# Steps Missed in integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am unable to figure the following step

$$\int_{-a}^0\frac{f(-x)}{1+e^x}dx=\int^{a}_0\frac{e^tf(t)}{1+e^t}dt. $$

I would appreciate any elaboration. I know, it might have something to do with $$\int_0^af(x)dx=\int_0^af(x-a)dx;(???)$$ and some trivial substitution.
I still cannot manage to compute it.

If you are interested, this step came while trying to prove 
$$\int_{-a}^a\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx=\int^{a}_0f(x)dx$$. Provided, f is even and continuous on given intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Make the change of variables $ t = -x $ and simplify the integrand.

Comment: I loose my mind once in a while. sorry. thanks.

Comment: @user1709828: No problem. It happens to everyone. We are humans.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\,u=-x\Longrightarrow dx=-du\,$ in

$$\int\limits_{-a}^0\frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx=\int\limits_0^a\frac{f(u)}{1+e^{-u}}du=\int\limits_0^a\frac{e^uf(u)}{1+e^u}du\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

It is a $u$ substitution with $t=-x$ followed by multiplying numerator and denominator by $e^t$ and switching the limits to change the sign

$$\int_{-a}^0\frac{f(-x)}{1+e^x}dx=-\int_{a}^0\frac{f(t)}{1+e^{-t}}dt=\int^{a}_0\frac{e^tf(t)}{1+e^t}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ -x = t, dx = -dt$

if $x = -a, \mbox{then } t= a$

and if  $x =0 \mbox{ then } t = 0$

$$
\int_{-a}^0\frac{f(-x)}{1+e^x}dx=
\int^{0}_a\frac{f(t)}{1+e^{-t}}(-dt) = 
\int^{a}_0\frac{f(t)}{1+e^{-t}}(dt) =
\int^{a}_0\frac{e^{t}f(t)}{e^{t}+1}(dt)
 $$